# DocuSign SOAP API + SAP Ariba Contract Management

Tags: docusignapi, sap-ariba

I would like to know if anyone here has already experience SAP Ariba Contract eSignature with DocuSign?
My Client would like to push their signatory workflow from Ariba to DocuSign directly.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to set up the link between DocuSign and SAP Ariba. On the administration panel (Manage > Administration), go to Project Manager > Signature Providers and fill out the required details.

Then, in your contract process, you will need a signature task associated with a workspace document or folder. This signature task will involve signers (either having the system group membership Document signer or belonging to a project group that has been given this permission).

When starting the task, the owner will be taken to the DocuSign site to set up signature placeholders, signature order, custom messages.

Once active, task members (signers) will receive a notification from DocuSign inviting them to connect, review and electronically sign the document.

Upon e-signature on DocuSign, the task status will be updated in Ariba to signed and the electronically signed document will be downloaded to the Documents tab, prefixed with "Signed_"